# Can´t write on *.tex

Tags: sharelatex

I would like to work in project i started few months ago. Today I have run *.tex file, and I can´t write on that file. I can use mouse and keyboard arrow but I can´t write.

Any suggestion?

Many thanks for help me.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! Which editor do you use?

Comment: Hi samcarter, edito? I work using Chrome. I access to Latex by Chome. First I use word for writting and then I copy and past in Latex.

Comment: Which online editor/page are you using?

Comment: I use Chrome, I have tried with Explorer and Edge and it does not work

Comment: Which website do you use in Chrome to edit your latex file?

Comment: This one: https://www.sharelatex.com/project/59402bXXXXXXXXXX. I am not the project owner and I am using free version Latex

Comment: @Amadeo This just gives the message "Sorry, we can't find the page you are looking for."

Comment: Samcarter, I can´t write here the complete link. Such is a investigation document.

Comment: Ask the person who owns the project, are you sure you have edit rights,  that your access isn't read-only?

Comment: Hi Torbjorn, I edited the document some weeks before without any problem. But now I can´t. Maybe permission has lapsed.

Comment: I don't know if there are time limits, but either way, I'd start by asking the project owner. If you do  have edit rights, but can't edit, then I'd ask ShareLaTeX for help.

Comment: I had edit right for shure. I have wrote all the document few week ago. Maybe I sould try from other computer...